# Can I use two Distribution Certificate or is there another solution for Swift and Enterprise Dist Certs?

Tags: ios, swift, ipa, crash, enterprise-distribution

First of all, sorry for my bad grammar!

I have this question and hope somebody can help me.

I work in a Mexican enterprise, we develop in house apps for sales, etc. and currently we started developing our apps in Swift.
Well, the point is that our Distribution Certificate where created in 2013 and the IPAs generated with it crashes when installed in a device.
Lurking about the problem, found that we have to re-create the Distribution Certificate and Provisioning Profiles for getting the Swift apps to work, but doing so, all the already distributed apps will crash sooner or later because of the change in the certs.

The question is:
Are we doomed to re-create all the provisioning profiles for all the existing apps in Obj-C, archive and re-distribute them again? or is there another way to get the old apps and the new ones to work simultaneously (like creating another Dist Cert and sign the new Swift apps with it), for I know, Apple is giving the chance to create a second Dist Cert along with the old one, but as far as I understood, it's just a support to re-distribute the apps when Dist Certs expire and not a long-term solution for a problem like this.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Every provisioning profile and certificate will expire one day, from that day on those apps will not launch any longer. You can see the end-date in the Apple portal where you created those.

There is no other way than to create a new certificate and profile and either re-sign the existing app with the new profile and certificate, or build the app with the new ones.